# How to use saveMany while assigining a value to a pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a many-to-many relationship in laravel with a pivot table that joins Products and Orders with an order_product table with the pivot value of Quantity.

Now I am able create the order and add each product in a loop using this:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $order->products()->save($product,["quantity" => 3]);
}
```

But, since I have to create entries with hundreds of products, hitting the database for every product does not seem ideal to me, so I'm trying so use this:

```
$order->products()->saveMany([$product1,$product2,$product3]);
```

My question is: How, in the second example, using saveMany, can I set the pivot value quantity for each product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use attach instead. saveMany is for one-to-many relation which doesn't have pivot table. If you have pivot table it's many-to-many relation. Then the code looks like that:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
   $data[$product->id] = ['quantity' => 3];
}
$order->products()->attach($data);
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: This solution assumes that the products are already saved. Isn't there a solution where we can bulk save the products with the links like ; prod1 = new Product(); prod1 = new Product(); $order->products()->saveMany([prod1,prod2], ["quantity" => 3]);

Comment: `saveMany()` can absolutely be used with a many-to-many relationship and a pivot table. And to @HarlanGray, yes, the solution is similar to what you describe. `saveMany()` accepts an optional, second argument, which is an _array of associative arrays_. The number of elements in the parent array must match the number of models being saved, so for the example given, it would be: `...->saveMany([$prod1, $prod2], [['quantity' => 1], ['quantity' => 3]])`. This would store Product 1 with a quantity of 1, on the pivot table, and Product 2 with a quantity of 3.